# Random Margin Bug

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, google-chrome

I cannot say this happens predictably, nor is it a functional problem, merely an aesthetic one. In Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140, 64 bit, I occasionally get the effect demonstrated in the screenshot below. The question is shifted about 100px below the title.

It automatically fixes itself upon refresh, so I don't know if this is a Stack problem or a Chrome bug. I have not tested it in other browsers.

[image: Example:]

Comment: Do you use the DuckDuckGo Chrome extension by chance?

Comment: Nope, I have AdBlock Plus, however...I didn't consider the possibility that an extension might be causing it...

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168943/everyone-loves-stack-overflow and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141554/broken-layouts-for-special-tags. Disable your adblocker.

Comment: I don't know if it works for your ad blocker, but with the one I use you can right click on the empty space, go to AdBlock -> Block this ad, and then slide the slider until it looks good.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not a bug in the site. Quoting (and slightly paraphrasing) [my own post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168945/140890):

> You are using an adblocker that leaves the div in place but blocks the image.
>
> You have less than 200 rep on SO, so you are still served [all advertisements](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads) *normally*.

Disable your adblocker, get a better blocker, or gain more than 200 rep.

Comment: *gain more than 200 rep* ... please up vote me ...

Comment: FWIW, I'm pretty sure this also happens with NoScript, which is not actually an adblocker. (It blocks third-party JavaScript, unless you add a specific exception; the fact that this ends up eliminating most ads is just a side effect that some may consider desirable. Personally, I'd have nothing against *seeing* ads on SO or anywhere else; I just don't want them running poorly written scripts that slow my laptop to a crawl and drain its battery.) But yes, I agree, this is basically SO and the extension both working as designed.

Comment: @rene can't really count how many times I have heard _get more rep_ from you :)

Comment: @kayess maybe [just one time 4 years ago](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/revision/805506/995154/comments-from-rene-regarding-get-more-rep)?

Comment: "You are using an adblocker that leaves the div in place"...but it doesn't normally...it's odd that it would do that only on Stack.

Answer (score 1):

This was happened to me also in the past. It was happened because I am using AdBlock extension... And ads are not displaying for every page-views... So you will see this margin for only some time.

Answer (score -2):

Did Chrome 64 block your ads? This is a new Chrome feature.

Comment: -1 because it s not block all ads.