# Why is there a big empty space between Ignored Tags and Hot Network Questions?

Tags: support, design

I open Stack Overflow daily to read those sweet entertaining Hot Network Questions, but it's annoying to scroll so much to get to them.

Is it designed this way? I don't see this on the other StackExchange sites.

I am using Google Chrome 85.0.4183.121 on Ubuntu 18.04, and see this on https://stackoverflow.com. I'm using an ad blocker.

When I disable the adblocker, the space persists for one second, then it is removed.

[image]

Comment: That is where the ads are, I presume. I have the same space.

Comment: Seems like the `.js-sidebar-zone` element.

Comment: Using uBlock Origin works for me

Comment: Similar issue with a the banner ads shown to users with < 200 rep: [Random Margin Bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363312)

Comment: @leonheess I have uBlock origin

Comment: @Snow I'm on Chrome (Windows 10) with uBlock and do not encounter this

Comment: Duplicate of [What's with the big blank div on the sidebar under HMP/Announcements?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400302/whats-with-the-big-blank-div-on-the-sidebar-under-hmp-announcements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your adblocker is causing this. There is [no support for using the site with adblockers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359993):

> While [we don't care if users use ad blockers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/), we don't really go out of our way to fix any issues that may arise from their use

Not all sites in the Stack Exchange network have advertisements, which is why you won't see this happen everywhere.

Either switch the adblocker off for Stack Overflow, or use a different adblocker.

Comment: Ah that's why I don't see it in the other sites. Thanks!